# Являются ли стандартные контейнеры потокобезопасными в C++11

Tags: многопоточность, c++11, c++

Здравствуйте. Вот возник такой вопрос в связи с тем, что требуется из разных потоков pop'ать одну очередь.

Если нет, то будет ли адекватной защитой для очереди обетование в *atomic* или стоит воспользоваться классическими мютексами?

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, не являются. Вам необходимо защитить контейнер при многопоточном доступе вручную.

Проблем тут несколько.

Во-первых, основное использование контейнеров — однопоточное, поэтому блокировки на уровне контейнера привели бы в типичном случае к катастрофическому снижению производительности.

Во-вторых (и это намного более серьёзно!) thread-safety **не является свойством одиночной операции**! Контейнер *не знает*, какова ваша семантика его использования, и какие инварианты необходимо поддерживать.

Пример: у вас есть два экземпляра `std::queue`, в одном вы храните название обрабатываемой книги, а во втором — номер страницы, которую надо обработать. Откуда контейнеру знать, что добавлять/убирать объекты из обеих очередей надо только парами? Если защищено будет лишь добавление/удаление из *каждой* очереди, другой поток может увидеть вашу структуру данных в неконсистентном состоянии.

Если же вы решите исправить проблему, и вместо двух очередей заведёте очередь заданий-структур, проблема останется: если вы получили доступ к одной из структур в очереди, и изменяете её, промежуточное состояние (изменены лишь некоторые поля структуры) не будет охраняться синхронизацией *контейнера*.

Другой сценарий ошибки: вы спрашиваете у стека, пуст ли он. Он может насколько угодно потокобезопасным способом сообщить вам о том, что он не пуст, но в следующую миллисекунду, когда вы попытаетесь прочитать оттуда элемент, как вы можете быть уверенным, что стек *всё ещё* непуст?

Comment: Спасибо за содержательный ответ.

Comment: Я пишу небольшую систему таймеров с ограниченным кол-вом потоков(которые тянут из очереди callback'и на исполнение). Думаю, что блокировка на уровне контейнера то, что нужно.

Comment: @deterok: На самом деле, у вас такие атомарные операции:

* добавить задание в очередь
* проверить, есть ли задание в очереди, и если есть, забрать его оттуда

Вот эти операции оформьте во вспомогательные процедуры и защищайте мьютексом.

Comment: @VladD, `pthread_mutex_lock()/pthread_mutex_unlock()` конечно замедляют работу, но вряд ли *катастрофически.*

Я померял на вставке в двусвязный список, для 10000000 вставок в хвост

    (/ (+ 558.0 598 584) (+ 421.0 437 441))
    1.3394919168591224

вот такие результаты в миллисекундах.

Comment: @avp: для вставки в хвост — да. А вот запись элемента в `std::vector` замедлилась бы сильно. Кроме того, есть и вторая причина из ответа, она намного важнее. (Например, проблема с проверкой, пустой ли стек.)

Comment: @VladD А стоит ли делать два списка для таймеров(остановленные и активные)?

Comment: Или проще обойтись флагом?

Comment: @deterok: как вам удобнее, можно и так, и так. Обратите внимание, что операция остановки или активизации таймера тоже требует отдельной блокировки в обоих вариантах реализации: в первом вам надо удалить из одного списка и добавить в другой под общим мьютексом, а во втором найти элемент под мьютексом и, не отпуская мьютекс, поменять флаг.